# undefined reference to 'strftime with Kinetis KL25Z Board and Codewarrior IDE

Tags: c, nxp-microcontroller

I'm trying to convert a tm struct to a string using strftime() in a Kinetis KL25Z using codewarrior ide.

When calling strftime i get an error saying "undefined reference to 'strftime'". Test code used below:

```
#include "derivative.h" /* include peripheral declarations */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct tm dateinfo;
struct tm *dateinfoPointer=&dateinfo;

int main(void)
{
    int counter = 0;

    char buffer[8];
    strftime(buffer,sizeof(buffer),"%H:%M:%S",dateinfoPointer);


    for(;;) {      
        counter++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: Aside: the `buffer` is too  small. *If the total number of characters, **including the terminating null**, is more than maxsize, both strftime and wcsftime return 0 and the contents of strDest are indeterminate.* (My bolding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be surprised if this function is implemented for your Cortex M0 uC. Usually `time.h` functions are not implemented or the functions are on;y the stubs. Programming such a small micros you need to forget your Windows/Linux programming habits.

So how to deal with time? Write it yourself :)

Comment: Like you said, after digging a little troght the time.h header, found that the function is not implemented at all. So, as you said, better rip off the time.h dependency and write the function myself.